# How to get additional props by OData in 1C?

Tags: rest, odata, 1c

I published Odata service and tried to get additional props by OData in 1C.
For example, I create user-defined property to entities "Warehouses". Let's call this the space where users can move the warehouse area in square meters.
But when I get Entity by REST client, the array of additional props is empty - [].
How can I do this, and what could be the reason for the missing value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you publish the OData interface, you use a special data processor to specify what data will be available through the REST API.
Since additional attributes of objects in typical 1C programs are usually stored in the "AdditionalAttributesAndInfoSets" catalog, try to open access via the REST API for this catalog as well.
You can see an article on working with OData: https://1c-dn.com/blog/synchronization-between-a-mobile-app-and-a-database-server-on-the-1c-platform/